# CORS ISSUES INCONSISTENT - 2 Examples (VueJS and NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have the following axis post request

**EXAMPLE 1**

*Front End*

```
let data = this.itemsDuplicated;
      console.log("length",data.length)
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${url}/upDateTasksFromProgress`,
        data: data
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
```

*Node*

```
router.post("/upDateTasksFromProgress", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "";
  req.body.forEach(el => {
    mysql = `${mysql} update tasks set startDate = '${el.startDate}', endDate = '${el.endDate}', duration = ${el.duration} where id = ${el.id};`
  });
  console.log(mysql)
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      resizeBy.send("Error with connection");
    }
    connection.query(mysql, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(result)
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

This works fine.

I also have:

**EXAMPLE 2**

*Front End*

```
let data = [];
      this.tasks.forEach(el => {
        let insert = {
          id: el.id,
          startDate: el.startDate,
          endDate: el.endDate,
          duration: el.duration,
          parentId: el.parentId,
          dependantOn: el.dependantOn,
          fix: el.fix
        };
        data.push(insert);
      });
      console.log(data.length)
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${url}/postTaskUpdates`,
        data: data
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
```

*Back End*

```
router.post("/postTaskUpdates", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "";
  req.body.forEach(el => {
    mysql = `${mysql} update tasks set startDate = '${el.startDate}', endDate = '${el.endDate}', duration = ${el.duration}, parentId = '${el.parentId}', dependantOn = '${el.dependantOn}' where id = ${el.id};`
  });
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      resizeBy.send("Error with connection");
    }
    connection.query(mysql, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json(error)
      } else {
        console.log(result)
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

The second example gives me the following error:

> “Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://www.testing-be.co.za/postTaskUpdates' from origin
> 'https://www.testing-fe.co.za' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.”

Both are in the exact same Route File on the backend.

The only difference is the number of records.

In the first example there are 22 records.

In the second there are about 1300 records.

Besides the number of records, all else is as shown above and to my mind exactly the same.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are both requests originating from the same page? How do you handle the OPTIONS request on the backend?

Comment: Hi, It is literally a copy and past then changing the data and the url. No they are not from the same page in the front. I have 50 or 60 post queries in different places yet this one is the only one giving issues.

Comment: Sorry, meant same site, ie both requests originating from `https://www.testing-fe.co.za`

Comment: Hi, no the backend is a different domain to the front end.

Comment: Well, you have at least one request originating from `https://www.testing-fe.co.za`  which is not contained in your origins you set at the backend ...

Comment: @derpirscher - sorry - replace testing-fe with cape-projects and testing-be with cape-projectsbe

Comment: Did you check in the webdev console of the browser if there is an OPTIONS request and what the result of this OPTIONS request is? Do you actually handle an OPTIONS request on the server? [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight)